# show random number from string

Tags: javascript

i have 5 different numbers. What is the options, to choose random number from string and return it? callback meaning callback function

```
function amazing(callback) {
    const num = callback(42, 128, 37, 81, 66);
    document.write("Num: " + num);
}
```

Comment: What is `callback`?

Comment: just a callback function -

Comment: From what string?

Comment: const num = callback(42, 128, 37, 81, 66);

Comment: you can also update your question (with the edit button) to add these useful comments along with your question.

Answer (score 1):

actually i found a solution, but may be it is another option?

```
function amazing(callback) {
    const num = callback(42, 128, 37, 81, 66);
    document.write("Num: " + num);
}


function test () {
    amazing((a,b,c,d,e) => {
        const arr = [a,b,c,d,e]
        index  = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        return arr[index]
    })
}
```